# Using ARRAYFORMULA and COUNTIF

Tags: google-sheets-formula, google-forms

I have a google form that asks different questions and each question has an individual correct answer.

In [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miDpd.jpg) example, the corresponding correct answers to each question are:

- Question 1 = A
- Question 2 = B
- Question 3 = C

The expected output for each cell in column A are:

- A2 = 2
- A3 = 1
- A4 = 1

This is my Formula in A2: `=ArrayFormula(IF(ISBLANK($B$2:$B),"",countif(B2:B,"A")+countif(C2:C,"B")+countif(D2:D,"C")))`

I want the formula to be able to automatically get the sum of all the correct answers of every row every time someone answers the form without having to drag the formula each time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

=arrayformula(if(B2:B<>"",if(B2:B="A",1,0)+if(C2:C="B",1,0)+if(D2:D="C",1,0),))

Comment: Edited my question since it was confusing -> I want the formula to be able to automatically get the sum of all the correct answers of every row every time someone answers the form without having to drag the formula each time.

Comment: Ok, then use this in `A2`: `=arrayformula(if(B2:B<>"",if(B2:B="A",1,0)+if(C2:C="B",1,0)+if(D2:D="C",1,0),))`

Answer (score 1):

`COUNTIF` doesn't work with `ARRAYFORMULA` as you want. You should sum each column comparision:

```
=INDEX(IF(LEN(C2:C),(C2:C="A")+(D2:D="B")+(E2:E="C"),""))
```

or use `MMULT`:

```
=INDEX(IF(LEN(C2:C),MMULT(--(C2:E={"A","B","C"}),{1;1;1}),""))
```

[image]